# Proving limit without using dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Since $|x^{1/n} \sin (x)| \leq \pi$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$ it is an easy result of the Dominated Convergence Theorem to say:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\pi x^{1/n} \sin(x) dx = \int_0^\pi \lim_{n \to \infty} x^{1/n} \sin(x) dx = \int_0^\pi \sin(x)dx = 2. $$

I would like to see how to get  the limit *directly* and *rigorousl*y using an $\epsilon - N$ type of argument if possible.  The convergence $x^{1/n} \to 1$ is not uniform on $[0,\pi]$ which rules out one approach.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would one want to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$\left|\int_0^\pi x^{1/n} \sin x \, dx - 2 \right| \leqslant \int_0^\pi |x^{1/n} - 1| \sin x \, dx \\= \int_0^\epsilon |x^{1/n} - 1| \sin x \, dx + \int_\epsilon^\pi |x^{1/n} - 1| \sin x \, dx \\ \leqslant
(\pi - 1)\epsilon + \int_\epsilon^\pi |x^{1/n} - 1| \sin x \, dx $$

Thus, since convergence is uniform on $[\epsilon, \pi]$ we have for every $\epsilon > 0$

$$0 \leqslant \limsup_{n \to \infty}\left|\int_0^\pi x^{1/n} \sin x \, dx - 2 \right| \leqslant (\pi -1) \epsilon$$

and this implies the desired result.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AlRacoon: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $|\int_0^\epsilon|\le\pi\epsilon$ for every $n$. The convergence *is* uniform on $[\epsilon,\pi]$.

Comment: I'm new without enough points, but I'd like to give you an up - vote for this.